# Standalone use of Quote, Orders and Standard Contract object is it possible in salesforce.com org without implementing CPQ?

Tags: cpq, contracts

We have a business requirement where we want to use standard Contract, Quotes and Orders objects.
I wanted to know if we can use and implement Contract, Quotes and Orders objects in salesforce.com org without implementing CPQ or without using any of the objects in CPQ package
Is it possible to customize and implement these objects on its own without CPQ implementation?

Comment: As with many yes/no questions about the Salesforce platform, the answer is "yes, but...". You could almost certainly create custom SObjects/Fields/LWC/Triggers/Actions/Flows to replicate what you don't have. Doing so, however, would require a substantial effort. However much time you think this would take, multiply that by at least 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So -- CPQ was an ISV (Steelbrick) acquired by SFDC to address more sophisticated product configuration and customer relationship lifecycles (like renewals, subscriptions) than the OOTB `Quote` object supported.

That said, if you have straightforward quoting requirements -- users add line items to quotes from the Product catalog and inter-lineItem validations are minimal-to-simple, you can give the OOTB `Quote` object a go and use Flow to populate Orders and Contracts once the quote is accepted by the customer.

There are some annoying things about `Quote` and `QuoteItem` (doesn't support field history) and there's no OOTB way to deploy the quote template.

The CPQ learning curve is much higher than OOTB `Quote` - but you can do much more with it and as requirements evolve, you won't be limited